# Поменять цвет Jpanel с помощью jmenuItem

Tags: java, gui

Объясните, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы по клику на кнопку (jmenuItem6) из меню менялся цвет JPanel1? Пробовал через .setBackgroung, но при нажатии ничего не происходит.

```
package javaapplication41;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents(); 
    }

    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField9 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField13 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField15 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField11 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField17 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel16 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        jMenuBar2 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu4 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu5 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem6 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Menthal Bank ver.1.0.0");
        setResizable(false);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(223, 248, 223));
        jPanel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jPanel1KeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/javaapplication41/newpackage/tumblr_static_sleepy_cat.gif"))); // NOI18N

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Сохранить");
        jButton2.setFocusPainted(false);
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Я просыпаюсь с ");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("единицами энергии.");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Я трачу на ");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("подъем с кровати");

        jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("завтрак");

        jTextField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("утренние проц-ры");

        jTextField4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jLabel11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel11.setText("дорогу");

        jTextField5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel12.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jTextField6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField6.setText("впиши что-то свое");

        jTextField7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel13.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jTextField8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField8.setText("впиши что-то свое");

        jTextField9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField9.setText("впиши что-то свое");

        jTextField13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField13.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField13ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField15.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField15ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel14.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel14.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jLabel15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel15.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jTextField11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField11.setText("впиши что-то свое");

        jTextField17.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField17.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField17ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel16.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel16.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jProgressBar1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(136, 136, 136)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addComponent(jLabel9)
                            .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel11)
                            .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(jLabel8)
                            .addComponent(jLabel10)
                            .addComponent(jLabel12)
                            .addComponent(jLabel14)
                            .addComponent(jLabel15)
                            .addComponent(jLabel13)
                            .addComponent(jLabel16))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 195, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel10)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel12)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel13)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel14)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel15)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel16))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel11)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 41, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jMenu4.setText("File");
        jMenuBar2.add(jMenu4);

        jMenu5.setText("Edit");

        jMenuItem6.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Y, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem6.setText("Светло-желтая");
        jMenuItem6.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem6MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenuItem6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu5.add(jMenuItem6);

        jMenuBar2.add(jMenu5);
        jMenu5.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleParent(jPanel1);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jPanel1.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    
   
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int c = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
        int d = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
        
        if (c>=100) {
        try {
            FileWriter FR1 = new FileWriter(jTextField1.getText(),false);
            FR1.write("У тебя" + " " + jTextField1.getText() + " " + "единиц энергии при пробуждении.\n");
            FR1.flush();
            FR1.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Не удалось сохранить ваш текст");
        }
        file = jTextField1.getText();
        jTextField1.setText(""); 
        jTextField2.setText("");
        jTextField3.setText("");
        }
    }                                        
        
   
    private void jMenuItem6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        jPanel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }                                       

                               
 
    int a,b;
    String file;
   
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);  
            }
        });   
        
        
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel16;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu5;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField11;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField13;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField15;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField17;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField9;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class JColor extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    // Названия цветов
    private String[] colorsNames = {"Белый","Черный","Бирюзовый","Желтый","Томатный"};

    // Цвета
    private Color[] colors = {Color.WHITE, new Color(15,15,15), new Color(0,255,180), 
            new Color(255,255, 50), new Color(255,50,50)};
    // JMenuItem-ы
    private JMenuItem[] colorItems;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JColor frame = new JColor();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public JColor() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu jcolors = new JMenu("Colors");
        menuBar.add(jcolors);
        
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        colorItems = new JMenuItem[colorsNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < colorItems.length; i++) {
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(colorsNames[i]);
            item.setName(i + "");
            item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    contentPane.setBackground(colors[Integer.parseInt(item.getName())]);
                }
            });
            jcolors.add(item);
        }
        
    }
}
```